# How to Use JSON Accumulate Method With List?

Tags: java, json, list

I am trying below code....

```
public  String listToJsonString(String keyName, List<StyleAttribute> attrs) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.accumulate(keyName, attrs);
        return json.toString();
    }
```

But when i am checking **json** variable it contains empty values something like below

> {"myKey":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}

And when i am checking **attrs** variables it contains 22 element Data.What i am doing Wrong here? I am just converting my List to Json Object and save to Database.
I am using

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONException;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code

```
public String listToJsonString(List<StyleAttribute> attrs) {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
            for (MyClass myObject: attrs) {
                JSONObject styleJSON = new JSONObject();
                styleJSON.put("name",myObject.getName());
                styleJSON.put("rollNumber", myObject.getRollNumber());

                jArray.add(styleJSON);
            }
            jObject.put("keyName", jArray);
        } catch (Exception jse) {
        }

        return jObject.toString();
    }
```

It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on this one but maybe the objects in your List are serializable.

Also, what library do you use to manage JSON?

**EDIT :**

So json-lib it is!

I found this in the json-lib FAQ :

> **Json-lib creates empty JSONObjects from my bean class, help me!**
>
> Json-lib uses the JavaBeans convention to inspect your beans and create
>   JSONObjects.  If the properties of your beans do not adhere to
>   the convention, the resulting JSONObject  will be empty or half empty.
>   You must provide a read/write method pair for each property.

Here's the wikipedia page talking about the JavaBeans conventions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions

Hope this will help you!

Comment: But that list contain a Java bean

Comment: If the objects in your list are indeed JavaBeans that respects all the JavaBeans conventions, I can't think of anything else. Maybe you can post the code of your JavaBean?